# Extract number right from right of brackets

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple items in a column that look like this:

```
1. (758,01) 1516,01€
2. (380,95) 761,90€
3. (480) 903,90€
4. (350,06) 700,06€
5. (344) 688,75€ 
6. (681,16) 1361,16€
```

And I wanted to know how can I do two things:

Extract the number between `( )` and the number next to `)` without the `€` part so that the final result is for example: `1516,01` `758,01`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways. You can use the `MID` formula to get get the numbers between `()`, likewise for the second half and just replace the `€` with a blank. This works if your data is in cell `B2`,

```
=MID(B2, FIND("(", B2)+1, FIND(")", B2)-2)
```

And

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(B2, FIND(" ", B2)-1), "€", "")
```